# how to generate a Google sitemap for Maven site?

Tags: java, maven, maven-site-plugin, xml-sitemap

Is it possible to generate [Google Sitemap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Sitemaps) by [maven-site-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-site-plugin/)?

Answer (score 2):

If you still need you can try  my sitemapxml plugin.

To test please run:

```
mvn site com.github.s4u.plugins:sitemapxml-maven-plugin:gen
```

After run you will have sitemap.xml in your site directory.

Next you can add this plugin to your project:

```
<project>
...
    <build>
    ...
       <plugins>
           <plugin>
               <groupId>com.github.s4u.plugins</groupId>
               <artifactId>sitemapxml-maven-plugin</artifactId>
               <version>1.0.0</version>
               <executions>
                   <execution>
                       <goals>
                           <goal>gen</goal>
                       </goals>
                   </execution>
               </executions>
           </plugin>
       </plugins>
    ...
    </build>
...
</project>
```

And plugin will run with standard command:

```
mvn site
```

More info about plugin you can find on site:
http://s4u.github.io/sitemapxml-maven-plugin/